# Beginner Android Dev Questions - Camera Specific Questions

Tags: android, image, sdk, camera, compression

i am learning to program android right now and i just have a few questions that i hope you guys can help me out with.

1) if i make my program invoke the camera and make it be able to take pictures and i want to store those pictures,  where do i make the store program them? in what folder?  in the assest or res folder?

2)  i want to send the images over to a server also, but i fear the image size would be to big.  is there anyway i can compress the image so it can be smaller and then send the small version?  or is there anyway i can take the picture in low resolution/quality to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

1) Your application upon runtime does not have access to change the resources/assets folder. You should be writing it temporarily to your directory OR you should store it on the Sdcard.

2) The Bitmap API has the ability to compress images given specific parameters. Check out the SDK site for more info.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can store those images to external directory or sdcard.

```
     String rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "nameofyourfolder";
                File rootFile = new File(rootDir);
                rootFile.mkdir();
                URL url = new URL(fileURL);

                File newFile=new File(rootFile,fileName);
                newFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

                InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }

                f.close();
```

2.) You can compress your image size:

```
    int nh = (int) ( bitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmap.getWidth()) );
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,512,nh,true);
```